# Possible to detected if a app is completly closed? In react-native / iOS

Tags: react-native

I've looked at several solutions, but those solutions either don't work or are only there when an app is down but not completely closed.

What I would like to achieve: A push notification should be sent when an app is completely closed with the info: Please keep the app open in the background.

Is this possible at all? If yes, how?
AppState only responds when the app has been minimized. But not when it is completely closed